# NSPageController swift example

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I tried to create Wizard with `NSPageController`. But i don't understand what do i need return in delegate methods. I attached `navigateForward` to my button and when i click on it i get:

> [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]

```
class BoardAligmentPageController: NSPageController, NSPageControllerDelegate {

    var orderedViewControllers: [NSViewController] = {
        return [NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "BoardAligmentStep1ViewController") as! NSViewController,
                NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "BoardAligmentStep2ViewController") as! NSViewController,
                NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "BoardAligmentStep2ViewController") as! NSViewController,
                ]
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        delegate = self

        self.arrangedObjects = orderedViewControllers
    }


    func pageController(_ pageController: NSPageController, identifierFor object: Any) -> String {

        return "\(self.selectedIndex)"
    }

    func pageController(_ pageController: NSPageController, viewControllerForIdentifier identifier: String) -> NSViewController {
        return orderedViewControllers[Int(identifier)!]
    }
}
```

Comment: never set delegate self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `orderedViewControllers` property isn't actually set (since you're getting a "beyond bounds" error).

Instead of doing that property, try doing it on demand:

```
func pageController(_ pageController: NSPageController, identifierFor object: Any) -> String {

    print("\(self.selectedIndex)")

    switch(self.selectedIndex)
    {
    case 0 :
        return "BoardAligmentStep1ViewController"
    case 1 :
        return "BoardAligmentStep2ViewController"
    case 2 :
        return "BoardAligmentStep3ViewController"
    default :
        return "SomeDefaultViewController"
    }
}

func pageController(_ pageController: NSPageController, viewControllerForIdentifier identifier: String) -> NSViewController {
    return self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! NSViewController
}
```

Comment: Could you help please one time more: how to place next prev buttons and send data between view controllers. I tried a lot and nothing worked:(

Comment: it's a different subject ; try it out as a separate question and I'll give it a shot!

Comment: help please, really spent a lot of time without results. How to build wizard like form ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938166/create-a-wizard-multiview-form